# In Django, how can I delete object inside template by clicking link?

Tags: python, django

I made a notification system. When "B" user comments at "A" user's post, notification sends to A.

This is my part of my code.

```
models.py

from django.db import models

from freeboard.models import FreeBoardComment
from users.models import CustomUser


class Notification(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOCIES = (
        ("FreeBoardComment", "FreeBoardComment"),
    )

    creator = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="creator")
    to = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="to")
    notification_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TYPE_CHOCIES)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    post_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-pk"]

    def __str__(self):
        return "From: {} - To: {}".format(self.creator, self.to)
```

```
notification/views.py

from django.views.generic import ListView

from .models import Notification


def create_notification(creator, to, notification_type, comment, post_id):
    if creator.email != to.email:
        notification = Notification.objects.create(
            creator=creator,
            to=to,
            notification_type=notification_type,
            comment=comment,
            post_id=post_id,
        )

        notification.save()


class NotificationView(ListView):
    model = Notification
    template_name = "notification/notification.html"
```

```
freeboard/views.py

...

@login_required
def comment_write(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(FreeBoardPost, pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateFreeBoardComment(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.comment_writer = request.user
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()

            # 포인트
            award_points(request.user, 1)

            ### NOTIFICATION PART!!!! ###
            create_notification(request.user, post.author, "FreeBoardComment", comment.comment_text, post.pk)
            ### NOTIFICATION PART !!! ###

            return redirect("freeboard_detail", pk=post.id)
    else:
        form = CreateFreeBoardComment()
    return render(request, "bbs/freeboard/free_board_comment.html", {"form": form})
```

```
notification.html

{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block css_file %}
    <link href="/static/css/notification/notification.css" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <ul class="list-group">
        {% for notification in notification_list %}
            <li class="list-group-item dropdown">
                <a href="{% if notification.notification_type == "FreeBoardComment" %}/free/{{ notification.post_id }}{% endif %}"
                   class="dropdown-toggle" style="color: #555; text-decoration: none;">
                    <div class="media">
                        <img src="{{ notification.creator.image.url }}" width="50" height="50"
                             class="pull-left img-rounded" style="margin: 2px"/>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h4 class="media-heading"><span
                                    class="genre">[@{{ notification.to.nickname }}]</span> {{ notification.comment }}
                            </h4>
                            <span style="font-size: 0.9rem;"><i
                                    class="fa fa-user"></i> {{ notification.creator.nickname }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

And what I'm trying to add is notification delete feature WITHOUT TEMPLATE(deleteview).

When user clicked the notification and redirected to url, I want to delete that notification.

Is there way I can do this?

Comment: Idk if what you're looking for is an Ajax request, you'd need to write some JavaScript for that, if you're using jQuery, take a look at the documentation in https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ Also, as it would be a POST request, it's a bit tricky, you need to configure jQuery to handle the CSRF token, take a look at this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/#ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you code is a little bit confusing but i here is the thing, i think it would be better to use [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and remove the notification without the redirection like @Edgardo_Obregón mentioned. or if you don't wanna use DRF, then it would be a good idea if you simply use a small view:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt # if you wanna bypass csrf, otherwise you can use csrf with ajax docs
def delete_notification(request,pk):
    if request.METHOD == "DELETE":   # optional
       notification = Notification.objects.get(pk=pk)
       if notification is not None:
          notification.delete()
```

[csrf with ajax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/#ajax) docs

Comment: Thank you so much :D